# MySQL query for login form not working in phpmyadmin sql query runner

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `users`(    
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
`name` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,    `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
`email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY `id`    
UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

That's my code for the query I'm trying to run in the phpmyadmin sql query runner to create a table for my users. When I try running the code I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
)ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE...' at line 7
```

Can someone please help me fix the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

here is the right syntax:

missing comma after pk , missing parentheses defining PK, and wrong syntax for unique key

```
CREATE TABLE `users`(    
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,    
`name` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,    
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
`email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,   
UNIQUE KEY  (`email`)
)ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, I figured it out I just added the unique key and primary key to the email and id columns. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score -1):

The above answer works but I did:
'''
CREATE TABLE `users`(
`id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
`name` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
)ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
'''
and it works as well, you can choose whichever. Thanks for the response eshirvana!